# What is the effect of instantiating the object from the subclass?

Tags: c#, oop

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubClass : BaseClass
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    BaseClass o1 = new SubClass();
    SubClass o2 = new SubClass();

    Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine(o2.GetType().Name);
```

Outputs are

```
    SubClass
    SubClass
```

What is the main difference between o1 and o2? In which cases is it necessary to define an object with BaseClass and instantiate it with SubClass?

Comment: You are merely assigning the instance of `SubClass` to a variable of type `BaseClass`. Sometimes your code doesn't need to know exactly which type you are processing. Taking the lowest common denominator as a variable or method argument, makes it easier to reuse code.

Comment: Like when you want to iterate over a `List<BaseClass>` which is populated with different subclasses.

Comment: Here an example`Stream target = inMemory ? new MemoryStream() : new FileStream( … );`

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is evident when you try this

```
BaseClass o1 = new SubClass();
SubClass o2 = new SubClass();
var name1 = o1.Name; // works
var price1 = o1.Price; // wont compile
var name2 = o2.Name; // works
var price2 = o2.Price; // works
```

This is becuase BaseClass doesnt have Price

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your question the type of the variable is irrelevant. For a more common example, you can have an *interface*:

```
interface IExample { ... }
```

and a class that implements the interface:

```
class Example : IExample { ... }
```

Obviously, if you manually instantiating the variable, or if you are using DI, it would have the class; but you typically assign it to the interface type:

```
IExample ex = new Example();
```

But any reflection tool will show you actual class.

Comment: interfaces are a special case because of a possible [explicit implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)